# Click a button in a tab with javascript

Tags: javascript

just wondering and not sure if this can even be done but is there anyway to click a button in a new tab that opens on button click with javascript?

```
<a href="#" id="target">Open Link</a>


(function() {
    var button = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-green')[0];
    document.getElementById("target").onclick = function() {
        var wnd = window.open("//LinkHere.com/");
        setTimeout(function() {
            wnd.button.click();
            setTimeout(function() {
                wnd.close();
            }, 2000);
        }, 5000);
        return false;
    };
})();
```

Comment: Where is `btn-green` element in your question?

Comment: the btn-green element is the button i want to click in the new tab

Comment: You control the new tabs site? Is it the same domain as the one you show here?

Comment: no i have no control over the new tab site and nope it's not the same domain i showed on here

Comment: If it's a different domain you can't interact with it for security reasons (it would be an open window to anything insecure you can imagine). The only way i know is if there is an API in this site to allow you do this action (something like a parameter in URL). If there is none and you don't control the site to add it, i would say you can't.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if what you are asking is possible without parsing URL parameters to the next page. Assuming you are the owner (developer) of the page you are redirecting to, the below is my proposed solution:

```
<!-- Initial page -->
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('target').onclick = function() {
            var wnd = window.open("myLink?clickButton=true");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="target">Open link</a>
</body>
```

```
<!-- Other page -->
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var urlString = window.location;
        var url = new URL(urlString);
        var clickButton = url.searchParams.get("clickButton");

        if(clickButton === 'true'){
            document.getElementById("myButton").click();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="myButton">Click me</button>
</body>
```